# How does Visual Studio Code Implement its Autocomplete Feature

Tags: algorithm, visual-studio-code

I am interested to learn how does Vscode implement its auto-complete list (in term of data structure and algorithm around it). I looked into [vscode repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode) but nothing jumped out right-away. Could someone point me to the right direction? Thank you in advance.

To be more specific

- What data structure does it use to store tokens?
- How does the lookup work given the data structure?

**Update**

Potentially found relevant codes:

- [completionModel.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/38f1eddf382e508e8be605ba6ef39c8a97e03a61/src/vs/editor/contrib/suggest/completionModel.ts)
- [filters.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/38f1eddf382e508e8be605ba6ef39c8a97e03a61/src/vs/base/common/filters.ts)

Comment: Every language has different algorithm I think, for example C# uses OmniSharp which is basically a hosted HTTP server giving you autocompletion etc. through JSON. It comes in form of plugins.

Comment: Thanks I'll check out omnisharp. It also does auto-complete based off of text in a file too-- The one that start with icon `abc`. Furthermore the look up part is also something I like to learn about.